# Tab instead of 4 spaces on visual studio code : Mac OS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I know that sound like a stupid question, and we can find many answer on google.

However, i've been trying for one hour and it still not working.

The question is prety simple, i'm coding on visual studio code on Mac OS.
And i want to instert tab when i press tab, and not 4 spaces.

It it supposes to be very simple :

Go on "code"->"preferences"->"users stting"

And add :

```
// Insert spaces when pressing Tab.
"editor.insertSpaces": false
```

Into : settings.json

However i have no clue why, but this is not working.

(I've save it, close visual, reboot mac, still not working)

Does anyone has any clues to help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might also need to look at editor.detectIndentation. If the file you are typing in was formatted using spaces, the editor would prefer spaces again. Does it also fail for a new empty file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (I've save it, close visual, reboot mac, still not working)

--> One thing is missing - did you try it with a completely new file? ;)

I just tried it, had the same issue and almost thought it is a bug, but it seems to be expected behavior as there is another setting `editor.detectIndentation` which is `true` by default.

If the indentation is detected then the detected value takes precedence over your defined setting. At first this seemed odd as others also reported in a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5276). But the analogy with CR/CRLF in this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3259) makes sense.

So as a quick fix you could set `editor.detectIndentation` to `false` or convert your existing indentation to tabs so that the next time you open the file the proper detection is done.